Designing a Chatbot with RAG Architecture: Handling Queries for Relational and Content-based Databases
I'm developing a chatbot using RAG architecture to respond to queries based on a collection of documents. Each document contains metadata such as author, title, and publish date, currently stored in an SQL database. The documents themselves reside elsewhere and are linked to the database through a unique ID (both the SQL row and corresponding document share the same ID).
I aim to address both relational and content-based questions. For instance, I want my chatbot to handle queries like 'What are the titles of the last 10 documents published this year?' as well as content-related questions such as 'What happened to King after the Apocalypse?'
I found that one type of database isn't enough. For relational questions, I'm using MS SQL, but for content-related ones, I'm experimenting with QDrant, a vector DB, because I want to understand the meaning of the content.
I understand that, to manage queries effectively across these databases, according to Langchain documentation, I need a Router method. My current plan is to always generate an SQL query. If the query pertains to content filtering, I'll direct it to QDrant; otherwise, I'll route it to the SQL server. Does this approach make sense, or is there a better way to do it? While it may work, it seems rather fragile to me. There could be numerous queries that I haven't considered yet, and I'd need to address each one individually.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
